# Folder Backup every 5 minutes (Applescript - Droplet)

Tags: applescript, automator, droplet

i am trying to write a script ;

1. dragging a folder to droplet
2. The script sets "dropped folder" as source
3. List item
4. Set target (different location)
5. rsync every 5 minutes.

this is my starting point.

```
set source to "Dropped_Folder"
set destFolder to "/Users/xxx/Documents"
do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -a  " & (quoted form of source) & " " & (quoted form of destFolder)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will create a stay-open droplet that lets you store up a list of rsync commands and execute them periodically. Copy/paste this code into Script Editor, then save it as an *Application*, with the *'Stay open after run handler'* checkbox clicked on.

- Drag and drop a folder onto the app icon to set up an rsync
- Double-click the app icon or click the dock icon to remove rsync commands from the internal list.

The app will execute all commands every `execInterval` seconds until you quit it, and resume executions when you restart it (unless you resave or recompile the app, which erases its persistant property storage).

```
property rsyncCommandList : {}
property execInterval : 300 -- 300 seconds is 5 minutes

on run
    if (count of rsyncCommandList) = 0 then
        display alert "No rsync commands set up. Drop a folder on the application icon to set up an rsync command." as informational
    end if
end run

on reopen
    if (count of rsyncCommandList) > 0 then
        set deletableCommandList to (choose from list rsyncCommandList with prompt "Remove unwanted rsync commands" OK button name "Remove selected" with multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed)
        set revisedList to {}
        repeat with thisItem in rsyncCommandList
            if (get thisItem) is not in deletableCommandList then
                copy thisItem to end of revisedList
            end if
        end repeat
        set rsyncCommandList to revisedList
    end if
end reopen

on open theseItems
    repeat with thisItem in theseItems
        set source to POSIX path of thisItem
        set destination to POSIX path of (choose folder "Choose a destination folder for bacups of disk item '" & thisItem & "'")
        set rsyncString to "/usr/bin/rsync -a " & (quoted form of source) & " " & (quoted form of destination)
        copy rsyncString to end of rsyncCommandList
    end repeat
end open

on idle
    repeat with thisCommand in rsyncCommandList
        do shell script thisCommand & " &> /dev/null"
    end repeat
    return execInterval
end idle
```